# Found a bug in Stack Overflow password recovery method, not able to recover password!

Tags: bug, status-completed, accounts

While performing password reset for my account, I found some difficulties and wasn't able to recover my account. After debugging the problem, I found that there are some issues with redirection between pages. Please go through the images attached below as I already have added detail description in those images:

[image: Screen 1 (After clicking the recovery link)]

[image: Screen 2 (Redirected after the mismatch of password)]

[image: third (Trying to recovery my account with correct passwords this time)]

[image: Screen 4 (No luck!)]

---

The bug appears to be if two different passwords are types on the initial recovery page, you are redirected to a different page without the `recoveryToken` parameter in the URL and shows a message that "The Password Do Not Match". If on this page the user types in the passwords correctly, nothing further happens and the user is constantly redirected to the same page.

Comment: I'll add this to our call for discussion tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: @Haney That will be great :)

Comment: This could be related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251003/258777

Comment: Thanks for the detailed report. I'm looking into a fix now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fun fact: we apparently took out password comparison out of our validation code when we switched to using only one password field during sign up instead of two.

I'm sure it made sense at the time. :)

The validation code is back in, so this issue will be fixed in the next build (`rev 2016.4.25.4441` on MSO/MSE, `rev 2016.4.25.3511` elsewhere.)